# Can not connect to Cassandra

Tags: python, linux, window, cassandra, debian

Newbie here,

I'm trying to get my feet wet with Cassandra. That sounds Naughty!

I have installed Cassandra on a VM running the LAMP stack. The Linux flavor is Debian.

I have a bunch of Python scripts on my native windows machine that I'd like to convert to query Cassandra.

I run the typical:

```
import cql

con= cql.connect(host="XX.XX.X.XX", port=9160, keyspace="mykeyspace")

cur=con.cursor() 

result=cur.execute("select * from users")
```

I end up getting this error.

thrift.transport.TTransport.TTransportException: Could not connect to XX.X.X.XX:9160

I'm able to query locally using cqlsh with no issues.

I changed the address of the rpc_address parameter in cassandra.yaml to the server address but still no luck.

What could I be doing wrong?

I'm a bit new to Linux please keep it simple.

Comment: Check the firewall at the server.

Comment: did you also set the listen_address?

Comment: I've set both rpc_address and the listen_address to the address of my server. Still no luck.

Comment: Okay, So I opened up the firewall and now i seem to connect but I'm getting a new error.  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cql\decoders.py", line 29, in name_decode_error
    % (namebytes, expectedtype, err))
cql.apivalues.ProgrammingError: column name '\x00\x00\x00' can't be deserialized as 'org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.CompositeType': global name 'self' is not defined

Comment: Oh, I needed to set the cql version to (cql_version='3.0.0'). We're all set now. Thanks! Mikhail, maybe post your answer and I'll check it off. "iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 9160 -j ACCEPT" was the command needed to set the firewall.